# sorting csv file with subfield

Tags: linux, sort, csv

I have 1 csv file space delimited,

```
Jan_high 32 123
Febr_low 19 139
March_high 12 63
Jan_low 36 18
Febr_high 87 99
March_low 83 77
```

how do I sort it based on `_high`, then `_low` string 1st column? I cant use `sort -k1.5` since the string high or low doesn't start at fixed character location. Does anyone have idea ?

Comment: What's the sample output?

Comment: cat file |sed 's/_/ /g' |sort -k2 |sed -r 's/\s+/_/'

Comment: Alternatively, `sort -t_ -k2` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-t '_' -k2` with `sort` would make `sort` consider the input as delimited on the `_` character instead of on the spaces, and then sort on the second field (the one starting with either `high` or `low`):

```
$ sort -t '_' -k2 file
March_high 12 63
Jan_high 32 123
Febr_high 87 99
Febr_low 19 139
Jan_low 36 18
March_low 83 77
```

Taking the first line of input as example:

```
Jan_high 32 123
^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^
f1  field2
```